# how to use unwind with input parameters in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to work this query in cypher. I want to make relationships between the nodes.

I've tried with unwind, foreach and other stuff. I've been trying two days and I don't know how to do it.

```
WITH 
 [
    {
      sender: 416,
      target: 400,
      bidirectional: true
    },
    {
      sender: 416,
      target: 509,
      bidirectional: true
    },
    {
      sender: 416,
      target: 413,
      bidirectional: true
    }
    ] as relationships
unwind relationships as relation
match (s),(t)
where id(s)=relation.sender and id(t)=relation.target
case relation.bidirectional
    when true
        merge (s)<-[:REL]->(t)
    else
        merge (s)-[:REL]->(t)
```

I've tried so many things but I can't resolve the issue here. Some ideas?
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All relationships in neo4j are unidirectional. If you don't care which direction is used, `MERGE` allows you to omit the direction from the pattern (or even put arrows in both directions -- which is a bit weird and misleading), but only a single relationship would be created (if necessary) and it would be unidirectional. So, the `bidirectional` flag is completely unnecessary -- you can just always have the relationship going in the same direction.

Also, a `CASE` expression can not perform DB reads or writes.

This query (which does not even need a `CASE` expression) makes more sense, and will work:

```
WITH 
 [
    {
      sender: 416,
      target: 400
    },
    {
      sender: 416,
      target: 509
    },
    {
      sender: 416,
      target: 413
    }
    ] as relationships
UNWIND relationships as relation
MATCH (s), (t)
WHERE id(s)=relation.sender AND id(t)=relation.target
MERGE (s)-[:REL]->(t)
```

Comment: Thank you for your clarification cybersam!